How to boot from qcow2 image using grub boot loader?
I got 4xVM in Proxmox instance on my testbed and all the guests VM are running ubuntu 24.04.
On proxmox I have installed grub2 as boot loader/manager. I would like to boot one selected system (using qcow2 format harddisk from VM) as bare-machine. Is it possible somehow?
I don't want to broke overwrite or broke proxmox instance. Just want to select propper qcow2 from boot loader and run it.
I know that I can convert qcow2 to raw drive and then boot from this drive but it would be "big work" every this cyclic task.

Why? What is the use case for this? Like, sometimes VM, sometimes a bare metal, and has to be qcow2. Normally people have hosts to run VMs and that's it, these hosts (even farms) run bunch of VMs and rarely rebooted to install updates to the platform. That's established practice. What are you trying to do? // Technically this is possible, just it isn't grub's work, but initramfs's init script. You must write your own script that builds the structure you need using qcow2 file. And, not only boot part will be tricky, but the clean shutdown too, because you would need to untangle everything back.

I want to schedule check performance of selected apps based on big db. No data copy - just reboot. This possibility would be awesome. I know other ways but this would be easiest in future using.

You should definitely consider employing CI/CD techniques for this; it appeared exactly for such purposes. What you are suggesting is a clear misuse of the technology. Besides, the performance test made this way would lead to wrong conclusions, since the qcow2 itself and underlying file system will add their performance impact in such a way that is impossible to predict and account, especially for the database-related case; therefore such performance testing would be misleading. Don't do this.
